# Formatting date from database

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to convert a TIMESTAMP date in my mySQL database when echoed. I have had this working years ago.

```
"SELECT id, date, title, summery  FROM blog_posts ORDER BY id DESC"
```

I'm sure it used to be something like:

```
"SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%e %b %Y'), title, summery  FROM blog_posts ORDER BY id DESC"
```

Firstly, can I set the mySQL field to TIMESTAMP so that I can have the entry date automaticlly generated? That would not stop me from then formatting the date on echo?

The ech I am using is:

```
<?php echo $row_blog_posts['date']; ?>
```

Is this also correct?

Comment: Before you all say, I know that in my question there is a typo on DATE_FORMAT :)

Comment: Personally I would switch to datetime instead of timestamp, as its easier to understand the data when viewing it with phpMyAdmin (unless it a last updated field which changes), you can then `strtotime($row_blog_posts['date']);` to get a timestamp in php or `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)` in mysql.

Comment: Are you asking in a forum so you don't need to read the format codes for [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) in the manual?

Answer (score 2):

To get a timestamp set automatically, just add a new timestamp column with the default as 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'.

And Ed Gibbs answered the date question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can format a `TIMESTAMP` with `DATE_FORMAT`. When I tried this on the MySQL command line:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '%e %b %Y');
```

I got this result:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| date_format(current_timestamp, '%e %b %Y') |
+--------------------------------------------+
| 30 May 2013                                |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Your echo will work if you alias the formatted column as `date`:

```
SELECT
  id, 
  DATE_FORMAT(date, '%e %b %Y') as `date`,
  title,
  summery
FROM blog_posts
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

instead formatting date in mysql better will be formatting of raw timestamp field in php

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($row_blog_posts['date'])); ?>
```

Comment: All that is producitng is: 1970-01-01 01:33

Comment: it should be date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($row_blog_posts['date'])); as @Waygood pointed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

I don't think it's possible to automatically tell MySQL to change the format it returns the date, but from a maintenance standpoint, you're much better using formatting in PHP using strtotime() and date() because if you ever want to change the format, it's much easier to do in code, especially if you want to use the same date/time in a different format somewhere else.